# Total number of rows in UITableView with multiple sections

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I need to calculate the total number of rows in my `UITableView`, however I have multiple sections. Is there a property on the table view I can access? If not, how can I find this information?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create an "Objective-c Category" of `UITableView` from the new file dialogue of xCode and add this method to it:

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfRowsInTotal{
    NSInteger sections = self.numberOfSections;
    NSInteger cellCount = 0;
    for (NSInteger i = 0; i < sections; i++) {
        cellCount += [self numberOfRowsInSection:i];
    }

    return cellCount;
}
```

Then import your category header into any class that you need to access this method in et voila, you have what you're looking for.

Answer (score 4):

You can easily calculate this value by iterating through each section.

```
NSUInteger allRows = 0;
for(NSInteger i = 0; i < [tableview numberOfSections]; i++)
{
        allRows += [tableview numberOfRowsInSection:i];
}
```

If you would like a property you can easily add the above code to a category for `UITableView`.

Answer (score 1):

A UITableView doesn't know how many sections or rows it has, but your table view data source does. Iterate over the sections and add up the number of rows in each, if that's what you need to do. There may be an easier way, depending on how you're storing the data.